# How did YogaNarasimha come into being

Tags: vishnu, narasimha

Am interested to learn about Lord Yoga Narasimha. When this sankalpa came into picture?
Was it happened after killing of hiranyakashipu? and why this "Avastha" appear in front of us?
and any relation with LakshmiNarasimha avastha?

Is the moolamantra of Narasimha and YogaNarasimha same?